# Why this C code makes infinite loop?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count_cycle(int n);

int main() {
    int N; scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("%d",count_cycle(N));
    return 0;
}

int count_cycle(int n) {
    int N = n; int _N;
    int count = 0;
    int x, y;
    while(_N!=N) {
        x = N / 10;
        y = N % 10;
        _N = 10 * y + ((x+y)%10);
        count++;
    }    
    return count;
}
```

I've been just practicing the basic algorithm about the specific natural numbers that have cycle which is represented above. But this code's result is infinite loop. 
My intended pseudo-code is like this.

```
function count_cycle    
count = 0
    ==loop==
    N = 10x + y (0 <= x,y <= 9)
    N' = 10 * y + (x+y) mod 10 
    if N' == N then 
        break;
    else then 
        N = N' 
        count++ 
        continue;
    ====
return count
```

How should I make this code work properly?

Comment: You do not initialize `_N`

Comment: What is the initial value of `_N`? In C, uninitialized local variables are really uninitialized, and their values will be *indeterminate* (and seemingly random).

Comment: `int _N` is equal to what when you compare it to `N` the first time? Also, choose another name. An underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved to the implementation for **any use**.

Comment: Also (but unrelated to your problem) symbols starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_N`) are *reserved* in all scopes. You should not define any such names anywhere.

Comment: As a way to solve your problem, perhaps you should consider a `do ... while` loop instead?

Comment: Furthermore, your question belongs to a category described [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: read compiler warnings first

Comment: Check return value of scanf. Turn on compiler warnings (*-Wall -Wextra* for clang and gcc) and fix them. Add debug prints to see values of variables every loop iteration. Basic debugging...

Comment: [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11962457/694733)

Comment: Ignoring the uninitialized variable and the other bugs there is nothing that changes in the loop. Either it will end after the first time, or keep doing the same calculation over and over again. N never changes, x and y get their values from N, _N gets its value from x and y. The exact same calcuation is done over and over. Why would you expect the loop to not be infinite after one loop?

Comment: Maybe you could rephrase what you try to do with that code. What is your definition of a cycle?

Comment: Most likely not the issue, but the behaviour on using the token `_N` is undefined (don't start a variable with a single underscore followed by a capital letter).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You miss the initialization of _N, so it will never be equal to N and you will rest into the while loop forever

Comment: _N will hold an indeterminate value at the first lap of the loop, but after that it gets assigned a value. It would seem that the root of the problem is the algorithm, not the initialization bug.

Comment: Question: in the pseudo code what does it mean this syntax (0 <= x,y <= 9) ?

Comment: I think the result can be anything instead of just while loop forever. e.g. if you use clang with -O2, the count_cycle() do nothing. https://godbolt.org/g/6Md2tt

Comment: This isn't the reason. `N` never changes in the loop, so `x` and `y` never change either, so `_N` also never changes. So either loop is never entered, or will be infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

_N isn't initialized it might be having a garbage value

Comment: Garbage value isn't reason for infinite loop, because `_N` is assigned in the loop, so it will have valid value 2nd time. Garbage value could only make the loop to be never entered, or optimized out, but it can not really cause an infinite loop (ok, undefined behavior, theoretically it can do that too, but that's not in any way a reasonable result from a compiler).